# How to use FilterProp in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

As I have attached both the codes, I want to ask in the second code I have made a component of FlowRunStateTypeTab. Now using this function 'useFlowsMock(2)' data is created. As there are tabs I want to filter the different types of data and display them according to the tab. I think we have to use the FilterProp in a way to accomplish the task. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to Vue.js

This is the code for FlowRunStateTypeTab component in Vue.js

```
<template>
  <p-tabs v-model:selected="selected" :tabs="tabs" class="flow-run-state-type-tabs">
    <template #heading="{ tab }">
      <template v-if="tab">
        <FlowRunStateTypeCount :state-type="getTabStates(tab.label)" :filter="getStateTypeFilter(tab.label)" />
      </template>
    </template>
    <template #content="{ tab }">
      <p-content>
        <FlowRunStateTypeTabDescription :state-type="getTabStates(tab.label)" :filter="getStateTypeFilter(tab.label)" />
        <FlowRunsAccordion :filter="getStateTypeFilter(tab.label)" />
      </p-content>
    </template>
  </p-tabs>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { useRouteQueryParam } from '@prefecthq/vue-compositions'
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  import FlowRunsAccordion from '@/components/FlowRunsAccordion.vue'
  import FlowRunStateTypeCount from '@/components/FlowRunStateTypeCount.vue'
  import FlowRunStateTypeTabDescription from '@/components/FlowRunStateTypeTabDescription.vue'
  import { useFlowRunsCount } from '@/compositions'
  import { FlowRunsFilter } from '@/models/Filters'
  import { StateType } from '@/models/StateType'

  const props = defineProps<{
    filter?: FlowRunsFilter,
  }>()

  const tabStates: Record<string, StateType[]> = {
    failed: ['failed', 'crashed'],
    running: ['running', 'pending', 'cancelling'],
    completed: ['completed'],
    scheduled: ['scheduled', 'paused'],
    cancelled: ['cancelled'],
  }

  const { count: cancelledCount } = useFlowRunsCount(getStateTypeFilter('cancelled'))

  const tabs = computed(() => {
    const tabNames = Object.keys(tabStates)

    if (!cancelledCount.value || cancelledCount.value < 1) {
      tabNames.filter(value => value !== 'cancelled')
    }

    return tabNames
  })

  const selected = useRouteQueryParam('flow-run-state', 'failed')

  function getTabStates(tab: string): StateType[] {
    return tabStates[tab]
  }

  function getStateTypeFilter(tab: string): FlowRunsFilter {
    const types = getTabStates(tab)

    return {
      ...props.filter,
      flowRuns: {
        ...props.filter?.flowRuns,
        state: {
          ...props.filter?.flowRuns?.state,
          type: types,
        },
      },
      sort: 'EXPECTED_START_TIME_DESC',
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
.flow-run-state-type-tabs .p-tab { @apply
  flex-grow
  flex
  items-center
  justify-center
}
</style>
```

Created a component of FlowRunStateTypeTab in the below code

```
<template>
  <ComponentPage title="DashboardTimeSpanFilter">
    <FlowRunStateTypeTab />
  </ComponentPage>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  // Import statements for the setup function go here

  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import { secondsInDay } from 'date-fns';
  import ComponentPage from '@/demo/components/ComponentPage.vue';
  import { FlowRunStateTypeTab } from '@/components';
  import { FlowRunsFilter } from '@/models';

  // Reactive State
  const selected = ref(secondsInDay);

</script>
```

This is the code snippet from a file where the FlowRunFilter is defined

```
export type FlowRunFilter = {
  operator?: Operation,
  id?: string[],
  notId?: string[],
  name?: string[],
  nameLike?: string,
  tags?: TagFilter,
  deploymentIdOperator?: Operation,
  deploymentId?: string[],
  deploymentIdNull?: boolean,
  workQueueNameOperator?: Operation,
  workQueueName?: string[],
  workQueueNameIsNull?: boolean,
  state?: StateFilter,
  flowVersion?: string[],
  expectedStartTimeBefore?: Date,
  expectedStartTimeAfter?: Date,
  nextExpectedStartTimeBefore?: Date,
  nextExpectedStartTimeAfter?: Date,
  startTimeBefore?: Date,
  startTimeAfter?: Date,
  startTimeNull?: boolean,
  parentTaskRunIdOperator?: Operation,
  parentTaskRunId?: string[],
  parentTaskRunIdNull?: boolean,
}
```

```
<template>
  <ComponentPage title="FlowRunList">
    <FlowRunList :flow-runs="flowRuns" class="color-mode-default" />
  </ComponentPage>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import FlowRunList from '@/components/FlowRunList.vue'
  import ComponentPage from '@/demo/components/ComponentPage.vue'
  import { useFlowRunsMock } from '@/demo/compositions/useFlowRunsMock'

  const flowRuns = useFlowRunsMock(5)
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add to your post the type definition for `FlowRunsFilter` and all additional data that may be required for us to help you?

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Are you filtering data inside the tabs, or are you filtering the tabs to display?

Comment: Basically I have different tabs. You can see their names in the first code snippet. Now I want to filter the data generated and assign them according to their state in each tab. The tabs are already created, I just have to filter the data and put it accordingly.

Comment: Where do you use `useFlowsMock`?

Comment: I have attached a code to show you how it is used in other components. Basically it is used to generate mock data.

Comment: I think there are still pieces missing for us to have a clear understanding of the current flow and relations between your components